# Retrieving emails from specific date

Tags: jakarta-mail, imap, yahoo

I'm trying to retrieve messages from a specific date using IMAP. (Yahoo mailbox )
This line should give me back nothing cause there are no new emails from this moment:

```
Message[] mlist = inbox.search(new ReceivedDateTerm(ComparisonTerm.GT, new Date()));
```

But insted it returns all of the messages in the folder Inbox.
Anyone now how fix it? I have tried every example I have found online and nothing worked so far... I don't want to go over mail by mail and check the received date...

Thanks

Comment: GT sounds like >, not =...

Answer (score 3):

Do you have any messages received today?  If so, you're probably running into [this bug](https://kenai.com/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=6526), plus the fact that IMAP date comparisons only consider the day, not the time.  You can try the [JavaMail 1.5.3 SNAPSHOT release](https://java.net/projects/javamail/pages/Home#Development_Releases), which fixes that bug.  If that's not the problem, please post the [debug output](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#debug) when this problem occurs, along with the received dates of messages in your folder.

Comment: Thanks! ill check that out.
I have found out I can use also SearchTerm with match method and that works great.
btw, check your link on "this bug" lol :P

Comment: If you call the SearchTerm.match method explicitly yourself, that will do all the searching on the client, downloading information about each message from the server as needed.  The Folder.search method does all the searching on the server, returning only the result to the client.  The latter is significantly more efficient.